# SQLite3 JSON1 Order by numeric index

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by, node-sqlite3, json-extract, sqlite-json1

I have a table like this:

```
TestTable
---------
data (TEXT)
```

All `data` values are JSON objects like `{ a:1, b:2, c:3 }`.

I want to be able to query the database and `ORDER BY data->b DESC` without a full table scan (indexed).

Is this possible in SQLite JSON1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function [`json_extract()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jex):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TestTable
ORDER BY json_extract(data, '$.b') DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5d7c62e39f1853e8c44c7fd958fc9774).

If the values for `b` are quoted then cast to numeric:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TestTable
ORDER BY json_extract(data, '$.b') + 0 DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4be47072783b77ee913d4c09732d0322).

Comment: If I make an index on `$.b`, will this operation use the index or do a full table scan?

Comment: @Lolums Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c8f528e28b9d86df9dcd85becb3f86e4 The index is used.